# Debug an install target in CLion

Tags: c++, clion

The dropdown menu in CLion only shows targets that are added using the add_executable and add_library commands in cmake, however the binary I want to debug is installed in "build" directory using 'make install' command - the one in cmake-build cannot be run due to missing configuration files and libraries.

How can I make CLion run the installed binary with the built in debugger?

Comment: I believe you're going to have to go through cmake. CLion can only give you the correct debug data if it has the intermediaries produced by cmake. I could be wrong though.

Comment: That's my intuition as well, but I don't know how to modify the cmake to achieve what I want

Comment: Sounds like a different question ;)